# Generic way to revert to old state if asynchronous action failed?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga

I am keeping all state in the store, and handle all async actions using redux-sagas.

So if I for example have an integer field, the changing of which should fire an async action, I connect the TextInput value to the actual value in the store.
As soon as the user changes the value and leaves the field, I dispatch an action. 
This will be picked up by a saga, which will call an API. But if that fails, I need the previous value restored. What is a good way to handle that?

Currently I pass the old and new value in the action, so that the saga can put a new action to restore it, but this feels like a kludge. Hasn't this been encountered before?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to restore the old value you will have to store it somewhere. However, rather than passing both old and new value to your action I would just remember the old value in your state.

Your state might look like this:

```
const state = {
  value: 5,
  oldValue: 4
};
```

Then when the value changes, you will update `oldValue` to `value` and `value` to new value. If the API call fails you can just set `value` to `oldValue` again.

Full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/0RORjNm8y

Comment: Two questions: (1) won't this lose serialisability as opposed to my putting the old value into the action? (2) unrelated, but is there a specific reason you used bindActionCreators() in mapDispatchToProps? Thanks for taking the trouble of creating a full example!

Comment: 1) You won't lose serialisability as you are still storing just simple values (no functions, classes, recursive references, etc..). On the contrary this solution will work nicely with time travel and other tools. 2) bindActionCreators is just a handy utility to bind all your action creators (wrap them in dispatch). Doing that yourself would work just as well.

Comment: Maybe I phrased it wrong. I mean.. a user could have edited the field twice, two async actions would be fired, if the second one that was fired, completed successfully before the first one, and the first one failed, that would unexpectedly restore an old value. My approach suffers from a similar problem, only it would restore the original (supposedly correct) value, your approach would restore the erroneous value after the first edit. Best option would probably be block editing while an async is running on the field.

Comment: So, basically you want a behavior like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/1y72w5p87 (use any other char than digit to make it fail)